# Setting a class property to another

Tags: ios, swift, global, var

```
var inputsContainerViewHeight: CGFloat = 150
var nameTextFieldHeight: CGFloat = inputsContainerViewHeight/3
```

The error says

> Cannot use instance member 'inputsContainerViewHeight' within property
>   initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.

Comment: So that are not global variables but properties of a class?

Comment: The problem is using self before the class is fully initialized.